# MVC remote validation approach

Tags: mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc5

I have a model, the model has 2 strings; `foo` and `bar`.

`foo` is what it is, it will be one of x amount of possible values (it's not an `enum`, though).

`bar` is entered by the user, so I want to validate it. But I want the validation to be driven by `foo`, and I want to use [`Remote` validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx) (to do it remotely).

My suggestion:

Create a controller `MyValidationController` with an action that the remote validation attribute will point to. To this action, I'll send values of `foo` and `bar`.

The action will then redirect to the action that corresponds to `foo`. So, if `foo` is "MyValue", I will call `RedirectToAction("MyValue")`. And the `MyValue` action will validate accordingly.

Assuming I've found a way to ensure this action exists, my question is:

Am I reinventing the wheel here? Is there a feature in MVC that would allow me to validate with a rule driven by a property submitted in the same form?

Comment: While I believe this is off topic, check out [Fluent Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/).

Comment: Great @GregBurghardt! Didn't know about this at all. Although - I don't believe it helps me point to a particular method/action/validation implicitly to validate `bar` based on `foo`'s value. Thanks again.

Comment: It can do exactly that. It just won't be with AJAX. You'll have to POST the whole form back and redraw the page with validation errors.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - thanks again, mate. Do you have an example of how you could use fluent validation to achieve this?